# Why Docker build need to use /dev/shm?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, containers, runc

I noticed the command `docker build` has a parameter `--shm-size bytes` which uses to set the size of /dev/shm. But I don't know why the `docker build` needs to use the shared memory.

The `docker build` command just follows the Dockerfile and run a set of intermediate containers to build the target container environments and commit them as an image. In this process, all parameters and commands in Dockerfile are resolved and packaged as a struct that passes in different components (docker client, docker daemon, containerd, runc ...) . It seems that `docker build` doesn't need a shared memory to pass the information.

But why `docker build` provides this parameter `--shm-size bytes`? And maybe I have some misunderstanding about this process. Please correct me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `--shm-size` option of [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) sets the `/dev/shm` size for intermediate containers that are started as part of the build process.